# Is it possible to add exe file into cx_freeze python bdist_msi?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I need to add ***RemoveDrive.exe*** into ***cx-freeze msi package*** and tried

`includefiles=['RemoveDrive.exe']`

in ***setup.py*** but, it didn't get added to the package

**Code:**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","shutil","datetime","subprocess"]}

includefiles = ['RemoveDrive.exe', 'whitelist.txt']
base = None

setup(  name = "whitelist",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("whitelisting.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: Do you add `includefiles` into `build_exe_options`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","shutil","datetime","subprocess"]}

includefiles = ['RemoveDrive.exe', 'whitelist.txt']
base = None

exe = Executable(script='whitelisting.py', base = base)

setup(  name = "whitelist",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My application!",
        options = {"build_exe": {'include_files':includefiles}},
        executables = [exe])
```

Comment: Thanks it works after changing include_files to includefiles

Comment: How about an explanation?